# How to pass a list and string into a generic method which has generic list parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following method

```
  private static void WriteReport<T>(List<T> report, string reportName)
      {
         using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@path)
         {
            for (var row = 0; row < report.Count; row++)
            {
               for (var column = 0; column < report.ElementAt(row).Count; column++)
                  sw.Write(report[row][column] + ",");
               sw.WriteLine();
            }
         }
      }
```

I can only pass in the above method the `List<object>` as parameter but I also want to pass parameter `List<List<object>>` in some cases. But I couldn't figure out the correct way to do so.

Edit : Cause whenever I pass `List<List<object>>` only then the nested for loop can be applied but if I pass `list<object>` then no nested loop can be applied and not sure how to structure my method to code it correctly

I wanted to know how to write a generic method to do so and also a bit curious to see if the generic method improves code maintainability and readability as well

Comment: You could write a metod handling both `List<T>` and `List<List<T>>`, but why not split the method into two, one for just `List<T>` and the other for `List<List<T>>` and force the caller to use proper method. You can check the type passed and direct the code to suitable method.

Comment: @prolog so far that's what I'm doing but I wanted to know how to write a generic method to do so and also a bit curious to see if the generic method improves code maintainability and readability as well

Answer (score 0):

You are not be able to convert T in List from T again, the solution that i see is to overload the method like this:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        WriteReport(new List<List<string>>()
        {
            new List<string>()
            {
                "Some Item",
                "Onather Item"
            },
            new List<string>()
            {
                "Test Item",
                "Demo Item"
            }
        }, "Report Name");
    }

    private static void WriteReport<T>(List<T> report, string reportName)
    {
        foreach (var item in report)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

    }
    private static void WriteReport<T>(List<List<T>> report, string reportName)
    {
        foreach (var item in report)
        {
            WriteReport(item, reportName);
        }
    }

    private static void WriteReport<T>(List<List<List<T>>> report, string reportName)
    {
        foreach (var item in report)
        {
            WriteReport(item, reportName);
        }
    }
    private static void WriteReport<T>(List<List<List<List<T>>>> report, string reportName)
    {
        foreach (var item in report)
        {
            WriteReport(item, reportName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you maybe will need to show him how to dispatch between these two methods, like I did.

Comment: It happens automatically and it works with more overloads. He do not need to know which one to use.

Comment: True, I leave this question to you.

Comment: Thank you so much guys at this stage based on my need applying the if condition worked but I got your point of overloading method so in future if my program grows then I'd overload my current method. Thank you guys!! Your help is much appreciated!!!! :) :) :)